# Can Proxy replace VPN?

Tags: network, vpn, proxy

I was reading about proxy vs VPN, to summaries that one could say that VPN is similar to proxy with the addition of encryption for better security.

So I have a question, wouldn't it be better to use proxy instead of VPN?

Why we only hear about VPNs like: express vpn, nord ... while we never hear about proxies?

Do we really that addition security of VPN? a proxy security level will be similar to the standard security we get from browsing in a clean installed pc.

Comment: Why do you say that "a proxy security level will be similar to the standard security we get from browsing in a clean installed pc."? That's an odd opinion to have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A Proxy that encrypts your data is the same thing as a VPN?](/questions/215231/), [Difference between SSH Tunnel / Proxy and VPN in terms of security](/questions/200248/), [Is SOCKS proxy lest secure than VPN? How?](/questions/160586/)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich still not, if proxy can be used to change my ip then why we can't simply connect to proxy instead of vpn? won't it be much cheaper? why we have no such options as pure proxy

Comment: *"why we have no such options as pure proxy"* - sure there are such things, sometimes directly built into some browsers. But a proxy is only for the application making use of the proxy, whereas a VPN is for all network traffic and thus provides more protection.

Comment: Your question is starting to sound like "if we don't need encryption, then why don't we just skip encryption?" And that's a question that answers itself. The real issue is the assessment of whether or not you need encryption ... therefore, the question you appear to ask is: what's the difference in security between a proxy and a VPN. You can then decide *for yourself* if you need one solution or the other.